# Disabling TextSymbol Scaling on Zoom in/out (ESRI JavaScript API)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, labeling

I am looking for a way to disable text scaling when a user zooms in/out on a map with a TextSymbol on it. It this possible?